# How to update a specific key of a specific record in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm storing some `Article` in MongoDB. By Article I mean this structure:

```
const articleSchema = new Schema({
    articleid: String,
    title: String,
    content: String,
    date: String,
    contributor: String,
    upvotes: Number,
    upvoters: [String], //<--------- I NEED HELP WITH THIS
    downvotes: Number,
    downvoters: [String]
})
```

I'm creating an API in NodeJS. Using this end point I want to add current upvoting user to be added in `upvoters` array in MongoDB:

```
router.post('/upvoted/:articleid/:userid', (req, res) => {
    Article.findOneAndUpdate({ articleid: req.params.articleid }, { upvoters: ["req.params.userid"] }, (failure, success) => {
        if (success) {
            res.status(200).send("done")
        }
        else {
            res.status(200).send("not done")
        }
    })
})
```

My problem is that the array is getting replaced entirely. I want to append this user into the same `upvoters` array in MongoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$push` operator to add an element to the array.

```
Article.findOneAndUpdate({ articleid: req.params.articleid }, { $push: { upvoters: req.params.userid }}, (failure, success) =>...
```

You can read more [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

Comment: worked like a charm. I'm accepting this as standard answer

Comment: However i was also looking at the same documentation but i somehow i skipped Operator thing

Comment: what if i want to remove one element?